Solving an integral equation in Mathematica
I have the following equation:
$$ V_I = v_0 - \frac{m G^2}{2 \pi \sqrt{\gamma}}\int_{\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}p \, p \frac{\frac{p^2}{2\sqrt{p^2 + \frac{p^4}{4}}}}{\sqrt{p^2 + \frac{p^4}{4}} + m\frac{p^2}{2} - p V_I}, $$
where $m, G, v_0$, and $\gamma$ are known constant parameters that I would like to input. Is there a way to numerically solve this equation for $V_I$ and obtain it as a function of $v_0$ keeping the other parameters constant? I wrote the following code just to check for one particular value of $v_0$:
v0 = 0.1;
m = 0.1 ;
G = 0.1;
gamma = 0.001;
E1[p_] := Sqrt[p^2 + p^4/4];
E2[p_] := E1[p] + p^2/2*m;
W[p_] := Sqrt[p^2/(2*E1[p])];
NSolve[V == 
  v0 - (m*G^2)/(2*Pi*Sqrt[gamma])*
    Integrate[W[p]^2/(E2[p] - p*V)^2, {p, -Infinity, Infinity}], V ]

However, it shows the following error:



How can I solve this problem? I have previously checked that the integral converges as well as a finite solution for $V_I$ exists when $V_I^2 + m^2 < 1 $. Is there a way to enforce this constraint while numerically solving this equation?
Edit 1
I originally made a mistake of not including the factor of $p$ in the integral, as pointed out in the comments by @Bob Hanlon. I corrected the mistake in this new code:
Clear["Global`*"]
v0 = 0.1;
m = 0.1 ;
G = 0.1;
gamma = 0.001;
E1[p_] := Sqrt[p^2 + p^4/4];
E2[p_] := E1[p] + p^2/2*m;
W[p_] := Sqrt[p^2/(2*E1[p])];
NSolve[V == 
  v0 - (m*G^2)/(2*Pi*Sqrt[gamma])*
    Integrate[p*W[p]^2/(E2[p] - p*V)^2, {p, -Infinity, Infinity}], V ]

Now, it has the following error message:




Your code uses Sqrt[gamma] where the equation shows gamma. Also, the equation has a factor of p in the integrand that is missing in the code. Edit the question to reflect whichever is correct.

Use FindRoot and NIntegrate.
Clear["Global`*"]
v0 = 0.1;
m = 0.1;
G = 0.1;
gamma = 0.001;
E1[p_] := Sqrt[p^2 + p^4/4];
E2[p_] := E1[p] + p^2/2*m;
W[p_] := Sqrt[p^2/(2*E1[p])];
f[V_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[p*W[p]^2/(E2[p] - p*V)^2, {p, -Infinity, Infinity}];
FindRoot[V == v0 - (m*G^2)/(2*Pi*Sqrt[gamma])*f[V], {V, 0.1}]

(*{V\[Rule]0.09859890332406149`}*)


I just have one question: What is the function of "?" in f[V_?NumericQ] in the code?

@sap7889 It's a PatternTest. Here it is used to create a definition that only applies to numeric arguments. Without ?NumericQ, FindRoot will give error messages.
